# Send animated GIF via e-mail in C#

Tags: c#, email, gif

I'm trying to send an animated GIF via e-mail using a Gmail account. I can send normal picture with this code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("my adress", "Kinomaton");
mail.To.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
mail.Subject = Kinomaton.Properties.Settings.Default.objet;
mail.Body = Kinomaton.Properties.Settings.Default.mail;
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"F:\gif_temp\gif" + (Kinomaton.Properties.Settings.Default.folder - 1) + "\\gif_final3.jpg");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my adress", "my password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Timeout = 500000000;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

The problem is that when I try to replace the .jpg file by a .gif file, it doesn't work. Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Any error you want to tell us about ?

Comment: It looks as though you are attaching a jpg?  "\\gif_final3.jpg");

Comment: Also, please make sure -- some email readers will not display animated gifs. In fact, most of them that I'm aware of will display an animated gif as a static frame. You may be attaching a gif appropriately, but not seeing anything on the other side due to security. Make sure your desired email reader will display an animated gif properly by sending one manually before attempting to troubleshoot this issue further

Comment: No errors are shown, the program just crash. 
In this example it's a jpg file but I tried with a .gif file, and it's not working.
I tried for the moment with a Gmail adress for the email destination

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Upload the gif to [imgur](http://imgur.com)

Step 2: Send an email containing the link to your gif

Step 3: Party

This will ensure that the recipient can actually view the gif. As mentioned in the comments, alot of email clients wont display gifs anyways.

*Edit*
To upload the file via code:

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key", "<api-key>" },
        { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"<file>")) }
    };

    byte[] response = w.UploadValues("http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml", values);

    Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response)));
}
```

The output will tell you what the link of the file is on Imgur so you can send it to whoever.

Comment: damn, i like step 3.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with ImgurSharp api. Is it a way to retrieve the link of the picture ?